# How do I define a shortcut key that snaps on off (toggle)?

Tags: interface, shortcut, keymap

How do I define a shortcut that snaps on off (toggle)?

[image]

Comment: Right-click on the icon and select Assign Shortcut?

Comment: Thank you so much for teaching
thanks it worked out

Comment: No problem. You can right-click on many items in Blender's UI and get popup menus with possible action. If there's no option to assign a shortcut you can often add an action to the Quick menu, to quickly turn options on and off for instance.